# how to deal with null value in array

Tags: php, mysql

i hav a query

```
  $sql="SELECT mstEmp.empname,mstEmp.cardno, InDate, dailyattendance.InTime,dailyattendance.OutTime, mstEmp.teamtype FROM mstEmp left JOIN dailyattendance ON (InDate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' )  AND (dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname ) WHERE mstEmp.teamtype = '$chk' ORDER BY InDate DESC";
```

now when i run this as print_r($row) it gives me array as [0]=absbd [1]=34 [2]=  [3]= [4]=
now i want [2] which is the date to display the date but it is giving me garbage value.

Comment: `foreach ($row as $element) if (!empty($element)) do something`

Comment: @PLB `if ($element)` - don't use `empty` unless the variable *may not exist*.

Comment: `empty` and boolean cast don't distinguish between `null` and other false values (i.e. 0) - is there a valid date returned by mysql that casts to false?

Comment: Also, is this a MySQL question?  Are you using PDO, MySQLi, or something else?  The question should probably be tagged accordingly.

Comment: What's the intent of this query?  To obtain the most recent attendance date of some employee for some repeating event?

Answer (score 1):

try this one..,

```
if(!is_null($var)){
    // Do ur stuff
}
```

Refer [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

Comment: This actually does the same thing as `=== null`... just slower due to the function call (as the comments on the page you referenced mention several times).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for null explicitly:

```
if($row[2] === null) {
    // Special behavior for null
] else {
    // Handle the date normally
}
```

Comment: tried this but i want [2] to show the date for which it has been selected from the database. look at the query above

Comment: Is `null` in that field supposed to be impossible, then?